# My arrayed object is not following the curve I've assigned to it using the Curve Modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I know there's probably been a million questions like this one, but can somebody help me sort this out? I'm making a zipper with the array modifier and trying to get it to follow a Curve I've assigned using the Curve Modifier, but it just isn't working properly. Here's a few pics of what I mean.

(Pic of the zipper and the curve object)

[image]

(Pic of my attempt to use the curve modifier on the zipper)

[image]

Comment: In what order do you have your modifiers?

Comment: Also could be a case of needing the object origins of both objects in the same place.

Comment: If it helps, my array modifier is first and my curve modifier is last. And both objects have their origins in the same place.

Comment: Then I suggest uploading the blend file [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so we can try and diagnose the issue.

Comment: Could you make a screen capture of the modifier settings?